# Why is this string matching condition in [[ ]] not true?

Tags: bash

```
$ tpgid=$(ps  --no-headers -o tpgid -p 1)
$ echo $tpgid
-1
$ if [[ $tpgid == "-1" ]]; then
>     echo "yes"
> else
>     echo "no"
> fi
no
```

Why is the condition not true? Thanks.

```
$ printf "%s" "$tpgid" > /tmp/test/fff
$ hd /tmp/test/fff
00000000  20 20 20 2d 31                                    |   -1|
00000005
```

Comment: always quote your variables ... then you'd see the spaces in front of the -1, as [DopeGhoti pointed out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/491795/117549)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though `[[ ... ]]` is "smarter" than `[ ... ]` or `test ...`, it's still a better idea to explicitly use numerical comparison operators:

```
if [[ "$tpgid" -eq -1 ]]; then ...
```

Further, your hexdump:

```
$ hd /tmp/test/fff
00000000  20 20 20 2d 31                                    |   -1|
```

shows that `$tpgid` expands to `"   -1"`, not `"-1"`; `-eq` knows how to handle this, while `==` is rightly doing a string comparison:

```
$ if [[ "   -1" == -1 ]]; then echo truthy; else echo falsy; fi
falsy
$ if [[ "   -1" -eq -1 ]]; then echo truthy; else echo falsy; fi
truthy
```

In short, the string matching condition is not returning true because the strings in fact do *not* match.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely is that `$tpgid` contains leading and/or trailing whitespace. Since the value is numeric, you might want to use an arithmetic expression:

```
if (( tpgid == -1 )); then ...
```